# Different DLL Verison when using ildasm or DotPeek

Tags: .net, dll

I tried to find out the used .Net Version for the compiled DLL.
For this I used ildasm which shows v2.0.50727 or v4.0.30319
Now when using DotPeek it shows me for the v2.0.50727 the Version 3.5 and for  v4.0.30319 it shows me 4.5

What is the difference?

Comment: That is the CLR version, not .NET version.

Comment: DotPeek is pretty misleading about this.  Ildasm.exe displays the metadata version.  If the assembly also contains a TargetFrameworkAttribute then DotPeek gets more specific.  A v2.0.50727 assembly does not have that attribute so it just fibs about it.